# Remote WMI connection

Tags: c#, wmi

I want to connect  to remote PC running Windows 7, from another PC using ManagementScope on a local network. 
On remote PC I've created a new user account "Samuel" without password and set as administrator.

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Username = "Samuel";
options.Password = "";

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\192.168.0.2\\root\\cimv2", options);          
scope.Connect();
```

The Error I get:

> Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

**Update:**
After setting password for the use, I get new error:

> The RPC server is unavailable.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Comment: If you go into Services is the WMI serivce running? and if so if you run the above code on the target Windows 7 PC can you connect to WMI?

Comment: WMI service is running there. And about running this code on the target, you mean running it locally? if yes, I can't execute code on that machine. (there is no VS or framework)

Comment: Is *Samuel* a domain or local account?

Comment: Samuel local account, domain is mshome

Comment: any final solution with full source code about it ?

Comment: To debug and troubleshoot, download http://servicesplus.codeplex.com/ it is an .exe then right click on the exe and Run As Samuel to see if you can access the remoter PC. If succeed you can download its source code.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe it's the missing 'EnablePrivileges':

```
scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
```

From MSDN ([ConnectionOptions.EnablePrivileges Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions.enableprivileges.aspx)):

> Gets or sets a value indicating
>   whether user privileges need to be
>   enabled for the connection operation.
>   This property should only be used when
>   the operation performed requires a
>   certain user privilege to be enabled
>   (for example, a machine restart).

Edit:
If it doesn't work, try setting the ImpersonationLevel to 'Impersonate':

```
scope.Options.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
```

> ImpersonationLevel  Impersonate:
>   Impersonate-level COM impersonation
>   level that allows objects to use the
>   credentials of the caller. This is the
>   recommended impersonation level for
>   WMI calls.

Comment: Trying to understand what "requires a certain user privilege to be enabled" means. To me, any WMI connection would require some sort of privilege. Does anyone have any further information about what operations would need this property set?

Comment: changing the `Authority` to my domain instead of "DOMAIN" worked for me

Answer (score 7):

- According to the [WMI FAQ](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx) on TechNet, the 0x80070005 error indicates a DCOM issue:

  > **0x80070005 (DCOM ACCESS_DENIED)**
  >   This error occurs when the connected user is not recognized or is restricted in some fashion by the remote server (for example, the user might be locked out). This happens most often when accounts are in different domains. Recent changes to WMI security can also cause this error to occur:
  >
  > - Blank passwords, formerly permitted, are not allowed in Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.
  > - WMI does not allow asynchronous callbacks to a Windows 98 client. A call like **SWbemServices.ExecNotificationQueryAsync** from a Windows 98 computer to a Windows XP computer will result in an Access Denied error returned to the Windows 98 machine.
  > - The DCOM configuration access setting might have been changed.
  > - If the target computer is running Windows XP, the Forceguest value under the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa might be set to force the Guest account off (value is zero).

  *(Although Windows XP is mentioned, this may be applied to Windows 7 as well.)*
- The 0x800706BA error, in its rurn, indicates a firewall issue:

  > **0x800706xx (DCOM RPC error)**
  >   This often occurs when a firewall is configured on the remote computer. You will need to open the appropriate ports on the firewall to permit remote administration using DCOM.

  Try enabling the *Remote administration* exception in Windows Firewall on the remote computer and see if it helps. To do this from the command line, run the following command in the elevated command prompt:

  ```
  netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote admin" new enable=yes
  ```

  You can also find the DCOM, UAC, Windows Firewall and other settings required for remote WMI access in the [Connecting to WMI Remotely Starting with Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa822854.aspx) article on MSDN.
- Also, since *Samuel* is a nondomain account, you need to grant this account DCOM *Remote Access*, *Remote Launch* and *Remote Activation* permissions on the remote computer as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393266.aspx#setting_dcom_security_to_allow_a_user_to_access_a_computer_remotely).

Comment: as I commented the previous answer: 
After setting a password i get this error":The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Comment: @shlomjmi: Try enabling the *Remote administration* exception in Windows Firewall on the remote computer and see if it helps. (See updated answer.)

Answer (score 5):

You got "Access is denied." because you cannot query scope connection with username only. You have 2 options: null for username and password or enter username and password.

You got "The RPC server is unavailable." because firewall doesn't let you query that machine. You have 2 options: disable firewall or add remote administration exception to it.

You can add firewall exception like this in cmd:
Older windows versions:

> netsh firewall set service type = remoteadmin mode = enable

Newer windows versions:

> netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Windows Remote Management" new enable=yes

If you try to login with domain user, change username to `domainName\username` or set connection property `connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:domainName"`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you can make remote WMI connections to accounts without passwords?

There are a number of things such accounts can't do (share files, remote desktop, for example).  Try setting a password and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: AFter setting a password i get this error":The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check to WMI Security Settings on the Remote Windows 7 PC.
Right Click Computer > Manage > Services and Applications > WMI Control > Security Tab
and make sure the user account you are using has the necc permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is denied because the WMI engine isn't listening on the remote machine, or if you have other login/connection issues.

Here's the code I used to connect to my remote machine, and it is working perfectly. Maybe it will help you:

```
ConnectionOptions oConn = new ConnectionOptions();
ManagementScope oScope = null;

oConn.Username = txtLogin;
oConn.Password = txtPassword;
oConn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:" + txtDomain;

oScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + txtHostName + "\\root\\CIMV2", oConn);

oScope.Connect();
```

If my domain/login/password trio are accepted, then Connect() will work. Otherwise, Connect() throws an exception. As long as the specified credentials have permission on that machine, you should be off and running.

Comment: I had two issues: 1) I copied example from Microsoft and had "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN", I didn't realize I had to put my domain there (duh).  2) I had put my domain in the user, which is not allower.  I put user="mydomain\myuser", but should just be user="myuser".

Answer (score 0):

Try to add domain or computer name before the username (e.g. @"mshome\Samuel").

Comment: look on jerry's answer and the comment below it

Comment: @prabhakaran: it is rather old question but I remember I had solved similar problem simply by adding domain name before user name but it was my particular case

Answer (score 0):

Solution using "net view \\*servername*"

I know it's not very desirable to use a console command and do some string-gymnastic on the output, but on the other hand it does work and it's not very desirable either, at least for me, to have to mess around with the DCOM default settings to to get the WMI way to work (at least on Win7s).

Has been tested on Win7 and XP clients and MS- and linux server.

```
Function GetShares(ServerName As String) As List(Of String)
    Try
        Dim P As New Process
        Dim Read As Boolean = False
        Dim Str As String
        Dim Shares As New List(Of String)

        With P.StartInfo
            .FileName = "net"
            .Arguments = "view " & ServerName
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .RedirectStandardError = True
            .CreateNoWindow = True
            .UseShellExecute = False
        End With
        P.Start()
        P.WaitForExit()

        If P.ExitCode <> 0 Then
            MsgBox(P.StandardError.ReadToEnd, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        Else
            Do Until P.StandardOutput.EndOfStream = True
                If Read = True Then
                    Str = P.StandardOutput.ReadLine
                    If Str = "The command completed successfully." Then Exit Do
                    Str = Strings.RTrim(Str) 'Removes any trailing spaces
                    Str = Strings.Mid(Str, 1, Strings.InStrRev(Str, " ")) 'remove Type
                    Str = Strings.RTrim(Str) ''Removes any trailing spaces
                    Shares.Add(Str)
                Else
                    If Strings.Left(P.StandardOutput.ReadLine, 10) = "----------" Then Read = True
                End If
            Loop
        End If
        Return Shares
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in """ & System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name & """: " & vbCr & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Runtime error")
        Debug.Print("--------------------------" & vbCr & "Error: " & ex.Message & vbCr & ex.StackTrace)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.I was trying to write C# code to get WMI information and files from a remote PC. And ran into two *`Access Denied`* errors:

To keep a long story short, I had to make changes to the remote PC. See below:

> 1. *0x80070005: Access is Denied:*
>      https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6229334e-d5ef-4016-9e7e-1c8718be8d43/access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-eaccessdenied-in-vbnet?forum=netfxbcl
> 2. *System.Management: Access Denied: Section "Using System.Management and WMI"*:
>      https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317012/process-and-request-identity-in-asp.net