# Get hardware information of Windows Server

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi, hardware

Currently I'm using following methods to get hardware information (network adapter, processor, hdd)

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ManagementObjectSearcher mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_processor");
ManagementObject dsk = new ManagementObject(@"win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""c:""");
```

My app is desktop, client-server (app and db are installed on server).
This methods get information for client. Is there a way to get hardware information for some node on lan - I want to get hardware information for server?

Comment: Take a look at this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289471/remote-wmi-onnection

There you probably get your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a subroutine I use in order to query remote hosts (here I assume I already configured WMI on the remote computer):

```
    public string getWMI(string[] parameters)
    {
        string ip = parameters[0];
        string username = parameters[1];
        string password = parameters[2];
        string query = parameters[3];
        string result = "";
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        ManagementScope scope;
        options.Username = username;
        options.Password = password;
        try
        {
            scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + ip + "\\root\\cimv2", options);
            scope.Connect();
            if (scope.IsConnected)
            {
                ObjectQuery q = new ObjectQuery(query);
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, q);
                ManagementObjectCollection objCol = searcher.Get();
                foreach (ManagementObject mgtObject in objCol)
                {
                    result = result + mgtObject.GetText(TextFormat.CimDtd20);
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            writeLogFile("WMI Error: " + e.Message);
            writeLog("WMI Error: " + e.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

In that subroutine I use a direct query such as "select * from Win32_ComputerSystem" but you can use **ManagementClass** as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get hardware information for server?

WMI can poin to another server as long as:

- The eserver exposes WMI
- The fireawall does not block it.
- Your user account has the rights on the other server.

Simple like that.

Comment: how exposes WMI ?

Comment: HOw get programmatically if firewall is blocked ?