# Finding windows services running on another machine under specific user

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, servicecontroller

I am trying to get the list of windows services that is **running on another machine** within my network. But I am stuck in finding the list of those service, which run under specific **"log on as"**. Please suggest if you have any idea?

I accomplished the first part using ServiceController class. But the second part I am not able to achieve. Code is pasted below:

```
public static void GetInstalledServices()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Get list of services...");

    foreach (ServiceController service in ServiceController.GetServices("MyOtherServer021"))
    {
        string serviceName = service.ServiceName;
        string serviceDisplayName = service.DisplayName;
        string serviceType = service.ServiceType.ToString();
        string status = service.Status.ToString();

        //GetLogOnAsForAService(serviceDisplayName);

        Console.WriteLine(serviceName + "---" + serviceDisplayName+ "---" + serviceType + "---" + status);
    }
}
```

As per **abatishchev** this question is already answered...But I want the code specific to fetching details from another machine. Please suggest a code for the same.

Comment: You may need to do a WMI query to [`Win32_Service`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418(v=vs.85).aspx), the property `StartName` has what you are looking for.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289471/remote-wmi-сonnection)

Comment: Thanks Scott. But can I query on another machine too?

Comment: @JustinSamuel Yes, you can make WMI calls cross machine if the correct ports are open (I don't know which off hand). See the link abatishchev linked to in his comment.